# Modelo de controle de estoque de produtos?

Tags: modelo-relacional

Estou criando um sistema e nele vou criar um controle de estoque de produtos, onde vou ter que gerenciar entrada e saida de produtos e verificar a quantidade de produtos em cada transacao de entrada e saida. Gostaria de uma opinião sobre o modelo, se da forma que fiz está correto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]